# Using Service for various operations

Tags: android

I am trying to make a FTP Client for Android. To avoid Network On Main Thread I am thinking of using Service. But I am confused.
How will I make my service do specific job when requested. e.g When I press connect button, the service should connect to FTP Server and list files. 
Now Can I use the same service to download files or upload files. If it is possible kindly guide me in right direction.
If not, please suggest what should I use to implement this.

Comment: Sounds like a job for... https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @sqrfv is correct, Async Task is the best way to go

Comment: For simple connection use the AsyncTask. When you want to do something in the background so that user will not see progress (like reciving mails or messages) - use background service. 
When you want to do something in bg and let user know about the progress (like file download) use foreground service.

Comment: Services still work on the main thread.  Using a service is a good idea if the connection needs to persist between activities, but even the service would need to use an AsyncTask or Thread.  And Thread may make more sense than an AsyncTask, as you'll probably want to keep the same connection open and reuse it rather than creating a new one per command.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks. Yes I want the same connection to last until the user clicks disconnect or quits the app. As I want to give static notification that you are connected to server, I will have to use `Foreground Service`. But problem is how will I tell service which action to perform

Answer (score 1):

First of all you will not avoid `NetworkOnMainThreadException` because Service is being run in the main thread. Secondly `Service` is supposed to be used in case of long-lasting background operations like music playing.

You should read about `AsyncTask`s and `Loader`s. They are designed to perform actions in background thread. 
I believe `IntentService` can be also useful for you. It is used to queue tasks and perform them in the background thread. Only one task will be processed at a time.

Comment: I want the same connection to last until the user clicks disconnect or quits the app. As I want to give static notification that you are connected to server, I will have to use `Foreground Service`. But problem is how will I tell service which action to perform

Comment: @Damandeep The service should be specific to the action it is performing. You should create a 'FTP Client' service, and the only action it will perform is the FTP work. You could also use service binding rather than a Foreground task. This site is a place for coding advice, and if you don't have working code, there is not much we can do to help.

Comment: You don't have to use foreground service to give a notification. Foreground service is required to make notification that cannot be removed by user (it will last until Service will be finished).

Comment: As I said `Service` itself runs in the MainThread so you have to create code that starts some background action, like `public void loginToFtp(String login, String pwd) { ... }`.